# Merge [gz] tag into [gzip] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

*I've been using Stack Overflow for some time and I thought it was time I started contributing to the Meta site:*

I recently noticed that there's a [gz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gz) with only 140 questions and very little associated information:

> .gz is a file format used by the gzip application that compress/decompress files.

This tag seems redundant given that there already exists a much more comprehensive [gzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gzip) with 2.9k questions.

> **gzip** is the name for the compressed data format used by the eponymous **GZip** application for compressing and decompressing data.

I'd like to suggest merging the [gz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gz) tag into [gzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gzip).

Comment: are all questions about [gz] about the format and not about the tool? if yes, then yeah. Otherwise we may want to check more closely that.

Comment: @Braiam From what I can tell, both tags include questions about different software implementations such as web server HTTP transfers, PHP's `gzcompress` function, automatic decompression by text editors such as Vim, etc. Both tags also include questions about the file format itself as specified in RFC1950.

Comment: Ugh... that seems to be a tag "something to do with the gz format"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the tags should obviously be synonymized. Consider, for example, the [7zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/7zip) tag. It is synonymized with [7z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/7z) which is the extension 7zip files have. Another example is the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag (it has [js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/js) and [.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.js) tags as synonyms) and many more.

This also seems logical: when you are talking about a `.7z` file, you are *actually* talking about 7zip in general. If not, then the question is about files in general and should be tagged [file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file).